# How to access the same attribute from a class that is composed in two classes in c++?

Tags: c++, class, composition

```
class AtencionRealizada
{
private:
Paciente *persona;
Atencion aten;

class AtencionRecibida
{
private:
Medico* doctor;
Atencion aten;
```

The first class has a pointer to the patient and their checkup info while the second class points to the doctor and the same checkup info. They both depend on the other to fill in the information completely, so how could I access the same private attribute (aten)?

Comment: Remove one of the Atencion aten. Just put it in let's say AtencionRealizada, then make AtentionRecibida a friend of AtencionRealizada, in this way AttentionRecibida will have access to aten from Realizada. Just google about friend classess in c++ and you will know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Derive both classes from a base class that has a protected member 'aten'.